# Launchctl - submit command instead of executable

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

I know it's possible to submit the path of a program to launchd via

> launchctl submit -l label [-p executable] [-o path] [-e path] -- command [args]

But is it also possible to pass a command instead of a program? So, say make launchd execute "command" in "path"?

Comment: And what “command” exactly might you be referring to? If it’s a shell builtin, a shell needs to run. If a shell needs to run, you can just use a shell script.

Comment: @DanielB I'm creating a program that will use any command that the user wants to get executed at startup, creating a shell script for it seems like a rather hard workaround

Comment: I don’t get it. Please provide a complete example for using a “program” and another example for using a “command”.

Comment: @DanielB So, my program will have an API, you will be able to call my program then with the option to disable or enable a startup item, and if you want to enable one, you provide a command that should then be executed on startup. So basically, my program gets a command and then it has to get that command to launchd, to get it gets executed on startup. An example command could be "npm start". So, if someone calls "./myprogram --enable --command "npm start", my program needs to get "npm start" to launchd. Edit: Obviously also with its path, this is just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, turns out it's actually really easy, I just couldn't read the synopsis of the command. To create a launchd service to fire, for example, "mkdir /usr/local/test", you just need to submit a service like this:

```
launchctl submit -l my-startup-program mkdir /usr/local/test
```

And you can remove it like this:

```
launchctl remove my-startup-program
```